# Alexa Skills Kit widget - "Problem installing widget - There were problems in your install widget request"

Tags: python, json, widget, alexa-skills-kit

I have a rather simple widget with APL, however, when I attempt to install said widget onto my Echo Show 10", a pop-up appears titled, "Problem installing widget" and with the message "There were problems in your install widget request" followed by a time stamp. For reference, here is the APL:

```
{
    "type": "APL",
    "version": "2023.3",
    "license": "Copyright 2023 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.\nSPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-.amazon.com.-AmznSL-1.0\nLicensed under the Amazon Software License  http://aws.amazon.com/asl/",
    "import": [
        {
            "name": "alexa-layouts",
            "version": "1.7.0"
        }
    ],
    "extensions": [
        {
            "uri": "alexaext:datastore:10",
            "name": "DataStore"
        } 
   ],
    "settings": {
        "DataStore": {
            "dataBindings": [
                {
                    "namespace": "widget_bin_datastore",
                    "key": "binData", 
                   "dataBindingName": "dsBinData",
                    "dataType": "OBJECT"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "onDisplayStateChange": [
        {
            "type": "Sequential",
            "sequencer": "displaySequencer",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "type": "SendEvent",
                    "arguments": [
                        "${event.displayState}"
                    ],
                    "flags": {
                        "interactionMode": "STANDARD"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "payload"
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "AlexaPhoto",
                "headerTitle": "Salford Bins",
                "imageSource": "https://i.imgur.com/B90CXAo.png",
                "primaryText": "${payload.dsBinData.bin_text}",
                "secondaryText": "${payload.dsBinData.postcode}",
                "buttonText": "Refresh",
                "imageHideScrim": true,
                "theme": "dark",
                "primaryAction": [
                    {
                        "type": "SendEvent",
                        "arguments": [
                            "widgetRefresh"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Edit: For additional info, here's the widget package manifest:

```
{
    "manifest": {
        "id": "widget",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "installStateChanges": "INFORM",
        "updateStateChanges": "INFORM",
        "presentationDefinitions": [
            {
                "url": "presentations/default.tpl"
            }
        ],
        "appliesTo": "${viewport.mode == 'HUB' && location == 'FAVORITE'}"
    },
    "packageVersion": "1.0",
    "packageType": "APL_PACKAGE",
    "publishingInformation": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "locales": {
            "en-GB": [
                {
                    "targetViewport": "WIDGET_M",
                    "metadata": {
                        "name": "Widget name",
                        "description": "Widget description",
                        "keywords": [
                            "keyword1",
                            "keyword2"
                        ],
                        "iconUri": "https://d3ozx4qyxcxwzd.cloudfront.net/default_icon.png",
                        "previews": [
                            "https://d3ozx4qyxcxwzd.cloudfront.net/default_preview.png"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

2nd Edit: Here's the request handler and the functions it uses:

Functions:

```
def get_access_token():
    return requests.post("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token", {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": "[redacted]",
        "client_secret": "[redacted]",
        "scope": "alexa::datastore"
        }).json()['access_token']

def _post_put_namespace(datastore_namespace, access_token=None):
    if access_token == None:
        access_token = get_access_token()
    requests.post(
        url='https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v1/datastore/commands',
        headers={'access_token': get_access_token(),
            'type': 'PUT_NAMESPACE',
            'namespace': datastore_namespace
            }
        )

def _post_put_object(namespace, key, content, access_token=None):
    if access_token == None:
        access_token = get_access_token()
    requests.post(
        url='https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v1/datastore/commands',
        headers={"access_token": get_access_token(),
                'type': 'PUT_OBJECT',
                'namespace': namespace,
                'key': key,
                'content': content
            }
        )

def put_bin_data_to_datastore(postcode, bin_colours):
    access_token = get_access_token()
    _post_put_namespace('widget_bin_datastore', access_token=access_token)
    _post_put_object(
        namespace='widget_bin_datastore', 
        key='binData', 
        content=str({
            "postcode": postcode,
            "bin_text": ", ".join(bin_colours)
        })
        )

def _check_user_events(handler_input, arguments_possibilites):
    for arguments in arguments_possibilites:
        if is_request_type("Alexa.Presentation.APL.UserEvent")(handler_input):
            user_event = handler_input.request_envelope.request
            if user_event.arguments == arguments:
                return True
    
    return False
```

WidgetRefreshHandler:

```
class WidgetRefreshHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return _check_user_events(
            handler_input,
            [
                ['widgetRefresh'],
                ['foreground'],
                ['background']
            ]
            ) or (
                is_request_type("Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.UsagesInstalled")(handler_input)
            ) or (
                is_request_type("Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.UpdateRequest")(handler_input)
            ) or (
                is_intent_name('WidgetRefreshIntent')(handler_input)
                )
    
    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.persistent_attributes
        postcode = attr.get('postcode')
        saved_collections = attr.get('saved_collections')
        timestamp_now = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        for saved_collection_day in saved_collections:
            collection_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(saved_collection_day, "%A %d %B %Y  %H:%M:%S").timestamp()
            if timestamp_now < collection_timestamp:
                bin_colours = saved_collections[saved_collection_day]
                break
        
        put_bin_data_to_datastore(postcode=postcode, bin_colours=bin_colours)
        
        return handler_input.response_builder.response
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in your cloudwatch logs at the time of attempted installation.  It sounds like you're getting a UsagesInstalled request but aren't handling it correctly.   Or perhaps the logs will show some other error e.g. an InstallationError request.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-datastore-package-manager-interface.html#requests

This only applies if you enabled the Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager interface though!

Comment: Funnily enough - I have checked the CloudWatch logs and yielded no logs at the installation time. I will, however, add a request handler and see how that goes. Thanks for the information.

Comment: If you haven't got one already, you should really have a request interceptor which logs *all* received requests before the request handlers are executed.

Comment: I see this request is as a result of turning on the `Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager` interface. Is this synonymous with the 'Data Store Packages' in the Build > Interfaces in the Dev Console?

Comment: Yes, that's how you enable the install/update/remove requests.  Did you have the interface enabled ?

Comment: So, I've added `"installStateChanges": "INFORM",` into my manifest, created a request handler for `"Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.UpdateRequest"` and... nothing. It still proceeds to come up with the same message, claiming there is a problem with the widget install request

Comment: Info - I've tried to switch `UpdateRequest` to `UsagesInstalled` and still no progress.

Comment: Are you receiving any request when the widget is installed ?

Comment: Nope - no such request. I've added a `LoggingRequestInterceptor` and found no such request of any kind.

Comment: To summarise all info I have to add to the main question - I have no CloudWatch logs relating to any sort of request (not just the `Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.UpdateRequest` or `Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.UsagesInstalled`), even though I have already added a `LoggingRequestInterceptor`. I have had the `Alexa.Data.PackageManager` interface turned on this whole time, and in my widget manifest, both `installStateChanges` and `updateStateChanges` are set to INFORM.