# Alexa skill not receiving UsagesRemoved request when widget is removed from the Widget Panel

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

I have an Alexa skill written in Java. I am beta testing a version of the skill that contains a widget. I have handlers registered for the following requests:

- UsagesInstalled
- UsagesRemoved
- UpdateRequest
- InstallationError

My skill successfully receives and handles the UsagesInstalled request. However, when I remove the widget from the Widget Panel, my skill never receives the UsagesRemoved request.

I know my handler is properly registered because I am getting log messages from the canHandle(HandlerInput) method of the class for other requests.

Anytime a request is sent to my skill I see a message in the CloudWatch logs that starts with, “START RequestId:…”.

When I remove the widget from the Widget Panel, my skill does not receive any requests. At least, nothing is getting logged in CloudWatch.

I have the following in the manifest for my widget:

```
    "installStateChanges": "INFORM",
    "updateStateChanges": "INFORM",
```

I see the same behavior on both an Echo Show 10 and an Echo Show 15.

Any ideas?

Widget APL:

```
{
    "type": "APL",
    "version": "2023.2",
    "extensions": [
        {
            "name": "DataStore",
            "uri": "alexaext:datastore:10"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "DataStore": {
            "dataBindings": [
                {
                    "namespace": "TeamAssist",
                    "key": "nextevent",
                    "dataBindingName": "DS_NextEvent",
                    "dataType": "OBJECT"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "import": [
        {
            "name": "alexa-layouts",
            "version": "1.7.0"
        }
    ],
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "payload"
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "height": "100%",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaBackground",
                        "colorOverlay": "true",
                        "backgroundImageSource": "${DS_NextEvent ? DS_NextEvent.backgroundImageURL : payload.nextEventDataSource.backgroundImageSource}"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaFooterActionButton",
                        "id": "nextEventWidgetLaunch",
                        "buttonText": "${payload.nextEventDataSource.headerButtonText}",
                        "primaryAction": [
                            {
                                "type": "SendEvent",
                                "arguments": [
                                    "openSkill"
                                ],
                                "flags": {
                                    "interactionMode": "STANDARD"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Text",
                        "id": "eventDateText",
                        "text": "${DS_NextEvent ? DS_NextEvent.eventDate : payload.nextEventDataSource.eventDate}",
                        "textAlign": "center",
                        "paddingTop": "${viewportSizeClass == @viewportClassMediumLarge ? @spacingLarge : @spacingSmall}",
                        "fontSize": "${viewportSizeClass == @viewportClassMediumXSmall ? @fontSize2XSmall : @fontSizeSmall}",
                        "onMount": [
                            {
                                "type": "SendEvent",
                                "arguments": [
                                    "localizeDate",
                                    "${DS_NextEvent.eventStartDateTime}"
                                ],
                                "flags": {
                                    "interactionMode": "INLINE"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Text",
                        "text": "${DS_NextEvent ? DS_NextEvent.eventName : payload.nextEventDataSource.eventName}",
                        "textAlign": "center",
                        "paddingTop": "${viewportSizeClass == @viewportClassMediumLarge ? @spacingLarge : @spacingSmall}",
                        "fontSize": "${viewportSizeClass == @viewportClassMediumXSmall ? @fontSize2XSmall : @fontSizeSmall}"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Text",
                        "text": " ",
                        "textAlign": "center",
                        "paddingTop": "${viewportSizeClass == @viewportClassMediumLarge ? @spacingLarge : @spacingSmall}",
                        "fontSize": "@fontSize2XSmall"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Text",
                        "text": "${DS_NextEvent ? DS_NextEvent.eventLocation : payload.nextEventDataSource.eventLocation}",
                        "textAlign": "center",
                        "fontStyle": "italic",
                        "fontSize": "${viewportSizeClass == @viewportClassMediumXSmall ? @fontSize2XSmall : @fontSizeXSmall}"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Text",
                        "text": "${DS_NextEvent ? DS_NextEvent.eventLocationDetails : payload.nextEventDataSource.eventLocationDetails}",
                        "textAlign": "center",
                        "fontStyle": "normal",
                        "fontSize": "${viewportSizeClass == @viewportClassMediumXSmall ? @fontSize2XSmall : @fontSizeXSmall}"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaFooterActionButton",
                        "id": "nextEventWidgetRefresh",
                        "buttonText": "${payload.nextEventDataSource.footerButtonText}",
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "bottom": 0,
                        "primaryAction": [
                            {
                                "type": "SendEvent",
                                "arguments": [
                                    "refreshEvent"
                                ],
                                "flags": {
                                    "interactionMode": "INLINE"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Widget manifest:

```
{
    "manifest": {
        "id": "NextEventWidget",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "presentationDefinitions": [
            {
                "url": "presentations/default.tpl"
            }
        ],
        "installStateChanges": "INFORM",
        "updateStateChanges": "INFORM",
        "appliesTo": "${viewport.mode == 'HUB'}"
    },
    "packageVersion": "1.0",
    "packageType": "APL_PACKAGE",
    "publishingInformation": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "locales": {
            "en-US": [
                {
                    "targetViewport": "WIDGET_M",
                    "metadata": {
                        "name": "Team Assist Next Event Widget",
                        "description": "Display the next event from Teamsnap.",
                        "keywords": [
                            "Team Assist",
                            "Teamsnap",
                            "TeamAssist"
                        ],
                        "iconUri": "https://d3ozx4qyxcxwzd.cloudfront.net/default_icon.png",
                        "previews": [
                            "https://d3ozx4qyxcxwzd.cloudfront.net/default_preview.png"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the widget version of the skill in development only ?  Some of the PackageManager requests only get sent for live skills.  This is definitely the case for the UpdateRequest as I got Amazon to add a note in the docs clarifying this.  Perhaps they've made some changes and now the UsagesRemoved request doesn't get sent for dev skills (although I would doubt this).

Comment: Yes, the version of the skill I'm testing is in development.  There is a production version of the skill, but it doesn't contain the widget.  Thanks for the tip on UpdateRequest only being sent for live skills.  I was not aware of that.  

I added a ReqestInterceptor to log all requests coming to the skill.  The interceptor logs the Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.UsagesInstalled request.  The skill did not receive a request when removing the widget from the widget panel.

Comment: I have received a similar problem - however mine straight up doesn't install the widget, returning an error message. Could you edit the question to provide the full widget apl and manifest? Potentially we can find a solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77698625/alexa-skills-kit-widget-problem-installing-widget-there-were-problems-in-yo

Comment: @CauseYNot, I appreciate the response.  I can't explain why, but my skill is now receiving the `UsagesRemoved` request.  I don't believe I changed anything relevant in my code.  I did log a support request.  It was still open at the time of this comment.  Maybe they updated something on their side.

I went ahead and updated the original question to include the widget APL and widget manifest in case it helps someone else.

Comment: @BrianW, I'll take a look and compare now. Thanks for all the information, hopefully I'll find a glaring error somewhere in my APL or lambda...

Comment: @BrianW, I have no progress on my end, I'm so confused. If it isn't too much bother, could you reply to my aforementioned forum with your handler for widget refreshes? Again, I hope this isn't too much bother and thanks again for your help.

Comment: @CauseYNot, I'm a new user.  Looks like my reputation is not high enough yet to comment on your other forum post.  I do have a couple clarifying questions for you.  1.  Have you been able to successfully deploy another widget to your Echo Show 10?  2.  Which ASK SDK are you using, JavaScript, Python, Java?

Comment: @BrianW I've not actually tested another widget, that seems like a smart idea. However, to answer your other question, I'm using Python ASKSDK, to my knowledge it shouldn't be a problem. I'll get the widget thing checked though, thanks.

Comment: @BrianW Yup, the error still comes up. I'll post more info on my request handler on my forum, see where I can get with that.